# EProblema con uso de ORM de Django para consultas

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de `Django` y se me presento un problema. Tengo el siguiente modelo:

```
class Chats(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(Usuarios)
    messages = models.ManyToManyField(Messages)
    # manager
    objects = ChatsManager()
```

La idea es que cada `Chat` almacene en su columna `users` una lista de los dos usuarios que componen ese `Chat`. Pues bien, el problema viene dado en el `manager` de ese modelo, especificamente en un metodo llamado `chatBetween`:

```
def _chatBetween(self, id_1, id_2):
    """
        Busca el chat entre el usuario con id_1 y id_2, en caso de no existir
        retorna None
    """
    chat = self.get(users__id__in=[id])
    return chat[0] if chat else None
```

La idea con este método, como lo indica su documentación, es que retorne el `Chat` que exista entre los usuarios con `id_1` y `id_2`. Como podría solucionar este problema evitando el uso de operaciones con `Python`?

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre la solucion, se tendria que hacer un filtrado doble en la consulta:

```
    chat = self.filter(users__id=id_1).filter(users__id=id_2)
```